# Background-image placement on Bootstrap carousel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, background-image

I'm trying to put a background-image on right and left sides of a carousel. The issue is that the carousel has **set-width(max-width:1000px)** and **margin:auto** for centering, thus there is no space to put an overlay or background image around the carousel. Is there a way to place the background image behind the carousel?

The screenshot of the page is given below
[image: screenshot of project page]

Comment: Please provide your [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sorry about that. I will do that from now on.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the carousel in a container div with 100% width and put the background image on that.

```
<div class = "div-with-background-image">
  <div class = "carousel">
    <!-- carousel stuff in here -->
  </div>
</div>
```